# pgfgantt: How to set random days of the week to real days of the calendar?

Tags: pgfgantt, gantt

Consider the following **Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

    \begin{ganttchart}  [ time slot format  =   isodate,
                          vgrid             =   { *{6}{dotted}, *{1}{dashed} }
                        ]
        {2019-01-01}{2019-02-28}
        \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname}\\
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

As you can see:

- days of the week from Monday to Saturday are displayed in `dotted` line style
- Sunday is displayed in `dashed` line style

---

**The question:**

The days of the week do not necessarily begin with mondays on new years. How can I set the days names to the "real" days of the week?

For example, in 2019 the first day of January was a Tuesday, not a Monday. How to change this behavior?

Comment: If you're happy with a ugly manual hack, you could do `vgrid =   { *{5}{dotted}, *{1}{dashed}, *{1}{dotted} }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly to tell you where (in my opinion) the problems lie. I tried to "hack" the `vgrid` style. The problem was that, when this code was executed, the start and end days are, according to what I find, not know. If they were, one could hack it. So, for the time being, I added some code that can be added inside the chart, i.e. when these dates are "known". There are certainly many loose ends, starting from the fact that `\y@mid` is not the right quantity to go for. Nevertheless, this code does draw a vertical grid in which the week days get distinguished from Saturdays and Sundays. Each of them are drawn in a style of the same name.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\tikzset{workday/.style={dashed},Saturday/.style={blue},Sunday/.style={red},
all days/.style={shorten <=2.5pt}}
\makeatletter
\newcount\pgf@currday
\ganttset{ivgrid/.code={\typeout{start=\the\gtt@startjulian,end=\the\gtt@endjulian}
\begin{scope}%[on background layer]%
    \ifgtt@includetitle%
      \def\y@upper{0}%
    \else%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\y@upper{%
        \gtt@lasttitleline * \ganttvalueof{y unit title}%
      }%
    \fi%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\y@lower{%
      \gtt@lasttitleline * \ganttvalueof{y unit title}%
      + (\gtt@currentline - \gtt@lasttitleline - 1)%
      * \ganttvalueof{y unit chart}%
    }%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\y@mid{%
      (\y@upper + \y@lower) / 2%
    }%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\y@size{%
      abs(\y@lower - \y@upper)%
    }%
\edef\idiff{\the\numexpr\gtt@endjulian-\gtt@startjulian}
\pgf@currday=\gtt@startjulian%
\gtt@currgrid=0%
\loop%
\pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\pgf@currday}{\myyear}{\mymonth}{\myday}%
\pgfcalendarifdate{\myyear-\mymonth-\myday}{workday}{%
\draw [all days,workday]
      (\gtt@currgrid * \ganttvalueof{x unit}, \y@mid pt) --%
      (\gtt@currgrid * \ganttvalueof{x unit}, \y@lower pt);
}{\pgfcalendarifdate{\myyear-\mymonth-\myday}{Saturday}{%
\draw [all days,Saturday]
      (\gtt@currgrid * \ganttvalueof{x unit}, \y@mid pt) --%
      (\gtt@currgrid * \ganttvalueof{x unit}, \y@lower pt);
}{%
\draw [all days,Sunday]
      (\gtt@currgrid * \ganttvalueof{x unit}, \y@mid pt) --%
      (\gtt@currgrid * \ganttvalueof{x unit}, \y@lower pt);
}}
\advance\pgf@currday by1\relax%
\advance\gtt@currgrid by1\relax%
\unless\ifnum\the\pgf@currday>\the\gtt@endjulian\repeat%
\end{scope}
}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{ganttchart}[time slot format=isodate]{2019-01-01}{2019-02-28}
        \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=shortname}\\
        \ganttset{ivgrid}
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is awesome! But could you get the first day of January as a common column as well? Right now the first of January is just the line at the left edge without any whitespace. :-)

Comment: @Dave The problem is that there is the frame. That is, there is a dashed line, but you cannot appreciate it since it sits on top of the frame (I think). To see this, try e.g. `workday/.style={dashed,orange}`.